# Argo Workflow use podSpecPatch to dynamically increase memory resource request in retries

Tags: argo-workflows, argo

I'm looking for a way to dynamically increase memory resource requests in Argo Workflow retries, based on what is described [here](https://github.com/argoproj/argo-workflows/issues/5471#issuecomment-803729050).
However, in my case, the original memory request parameters need to be taken from input parameters.
I have input parameters memreqnum (e.g. 250) and memrequnit  (e.g. Mi), and I'm trying to define a podSpecPatch
that will enable me to specify the memory request as a multiple of memreqnum (based on retries) with the original
memrequnit.
I have made all kinds of attempts, such as the following, but none seem to work:

```
podSpecPatch: |
  containers:
    - name: main
      resources:
        requests:
          memory: "{{={{=(asInt{{retries}} + 1)}} * {{inputs.parameters.memreqnum}}}}{{inputs.parameters.memrequnit}}"
```

The above podSpecPatch gives me the following error:

```
invalid podSpecPatch "{\"containers\":[{\"name\":\"main\",\"resources\":{\"requests\":{\"memory\":\"{{={{=(asInt{{retries}} + 1)}} * 250}}Mi\"}}}]}": quantities must match the regular expression '^([+-]?[0-9.]+)([eEinumkKMGTP]*[-+]?[0-9]*)$'
```

Can someone please point me in the right direction?
Many thanks!

Comment: Maybe this: "{{=(sprig.int(retries) + 1) * sprig.int(inputs.parameters.memreqnum)}}{{inputs.parameters.memrequnit}}"

Comment: Thanks @crenshaw-dev, unfortunately that results in the same error: 
`invalid podSpecPatch "{\"containers\":[{\"name\":\"main\",\"resources\":{\"requests\":{\"memory\":\"{{=(sprig.int(retries) + 1) * sprig.int(inputs.parameters.memreqnum)}}Mi\"}}}]}": quantities must match the regular expression '^([+-]?[0-9.]+)([eEinumkKMGTP]*[-+]?[0-9]*)$'`

Comment: @crenshaw-dev I think my problem is in casting the `inputs.parameters.memreqnum`  to an int, which for some reason doesn't seem to work with either `sprig.int(inputs.parameters.memreqnum)` or with `asInt(inputs.parameters.memreqnum)`.  Do you have any idea why that might be?

Comment: Unfortunately, no idea... afaik Workflows doesn't log the error. In the past I've had to set up a debugger and read the error message directly. My main suggestion would be to keep simplifying the expression until it works (even if it doesn't produce the output you want). And then add stuff until you have a complete expression.

Comment: Thanks @crenshaw-dev! So at the moment, what I did is: `memory: {{retries}}{{inputs.parameters.memreqnum}}{{inputs.parameters.memrequnit}}`, which is rather lame, and not exactly what I want, but at least works. I opened https://github.com/argoproj/argo-workflows/issues/10362 for the Argo team. I hope someone there might fix it...